# How to show that $S = \{a+bc\}$ is countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Say that $S =\{s: s= a+bc\}$ where $b$ is a fixed real number and $a \in \mathbb{N}$, $c \in \mathbb{Z}$. I want to show that $S$ is countable in a simple way. I thought that I could show that there is a bijection $\phi : S \to \mathbb{Q}$ since I know the rationals are countable. But if I just put $\phi(s) = a/b$ then this is only a bijection for coprime $a$ and $b$. Where should I map the other pairs $a,b$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need an injection into some countable set, not a bijection.  An easy one is $\phi(s)=2^a3^c$ for $c \ge 0$ and $\phi(s)=2^a5^{-c}$ for $c \lt 0$.  This injects into $\Bbb N$ and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $n\in\omega$, you know that $\{n+bc:c\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is countable, then
$$
S=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\{n+bc:c\in\mathbb{z}\}
$$
is countable.

Comment: Will the union of infinitely many countable sets be countable?

Comment: @Garou Yes, but only if the union is countable.